# kylin java.io.IOException: OS command error exit with return code: 137

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, kylin

when  i build cube , have an error ,

```
the error is :
```

[http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/b481d753ly1g0zuqbnkeaj21bd0p4q5d.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrMc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use capital letter when naming databases,tables and columns for kylin source data.It's a known bug in kylin as of version 2.3 .